# How can you check if there exists a valid magic square with given initial conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, magic-square

For example, if I have a $4\times4$ magic square that looks like so:

\begin{pmatrix}
\hspace{0.1ex}2 & 3 & \cdot & \cdot\hspace{1ex} \\
\hspace{0.1ex}4 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\hspace{1ex} \\
\hspace{0.1ex}\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\hspace{1ex} \\
\hspace{0.1ex}\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot\hspace{1ex} \\
\end{pmatrix}

How can I determine if there exists a valid magic square for which these initial conditions hold?

Answer (score 1):

In the present case, you can determine it by checking [this list](http://www.magic-squares.net/order4list.htm). There seems to be no such magic square.

In the general case, you can treat the emtpy squares as variables, introduce the $2n+2$ constraints and solve the corresponding system of linear equations. If you prescribe $k$ squares, this will leave $n^2-k-(2n+2)$ variables to choose freely. You can assign all possible values to them and check whether any of them make the entries come out to form the set $\{1,\ldots,n^2\}$; if so, you've found a magic square of the desired form. In the present case, you'd have $4^2-3-(2\cdot4+2)=3$ free variables, and $4^2-3=13$ numbers left to choose, so you'd have $13\cdot12\cdot11=1716$ combinations to try; an easy task for a computer.

Comment: thanks that helps a lot :)